# Mapping custom errors to http code by error's key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got this kind of object, let's call it `mapping_code` in which I store custom errors and corresponding to them http statuses:

```
const mapping_code = {
  [CustomError1.name]: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, // not sure what kind of key use here
};
```

And place where it's handled

```
export class ErrorHanlder extends HttpException {
  constructor(error: Error, code?: number) {
    super(
      error.message,
      mapping_code[error] // ?
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is, that I could add another errors to the mapping_code. Later on I want to map my custom error to http code. So I need to obtain value (HttpStatus) based on error (in that case CustomError1).
I've been struggling with that for a while, because `CustomError1.name` is not going to work since the error incoming in that 'handler' has already name 'Error'. I was thinking about using `error.constructor` but `CustomError1` cannot be the index of the `mapping_code`, because it's 'Function' type. So the case is how to reimplement `mapping_code` to have it working

Comment: could you tell where you imported the `HttpStatus`, i.e which library?

Comment: it's from @nestjs/common, sorry forgot to include that information

Comment: does ```mapping_code[error.name]``` solves your problem  or I missed something ?